# Testing ExtJS UI with WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, java, browser-automation

Our Web app is using [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) framework for rendering UI.

However, ExtJS-rendered UI is [hard to test automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107314/any-suggestions-for-testing-extjs-code-in-a-browser-preferably-with-selenium/219506#219506) because:

- For most clickable elements, ExtJS uses generated ids like "ext-gen-345" which are likely to change on a subsequent visit to the same page.
- Some elements require more than simple mouse/keyboard interactions due to the complex rendering carried out by ExtJS, e.g., JavaScript calls to ExtJS script must be done.
- Testing complex components like data grids/tables requires cryptic and unreliable CSS locators; for instance there is no easy way to access "zip code" cell of a row for user with X in column "name".

Is there a open source Java framework that simplifies that?

*Possible solution*: I started to design a set of classes wrapped around `WebElement` instances from Selenium 2, e.g., I would have:

```
class ExtJsGrid {

    ExtJsGrid(WebElement element) { ... }

    List<String> getColumnNames() { ... }
    List<ExtJsRow> getRows()      { ... }
    void selectRow(int n)         { ... }
    ...
}
```

I'm pretty sure someone else have already solved that. I have even seen InfoStretch released a library that provides such wrappers for a whole hierarchy of ExtJS components. Unfortunately, the library is based on Selenium 1 and I cannot modify that, as it is not open source: they provide only compiled classes.

Comment: The framework/library from InfoStretch is available open source named [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use component query.  From Webdriver you can execute arbitrary javascript - that means you can use ComponentQuery to get things from a high level and then drill down with (maybe) xpath to get more specific things.

This [article](http://developertips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/locate-extjs-component-selenium-web.html) helped me figure it out.

for example you'd probably use component query to get hold of a control and a button in that control (using itemId which you can set and are probably already using)

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('SomeNameSpace_MyControl_ItsName #saveButton');
```

from there you'd then use the click on the webelement retrieved.

For things like text boxes you'd follow up with some xpath:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('SomeNameSpace_MyControl_ItsName #saveNameField');
```

then:

```
saveNameElement.FindElement(By.Xpath("/input");
```

Im sort of paraphrasing there.  Let me know if it doesn't make sense.
Its also worth noting that you shouldn't actually try and haul back the objects themselves from the javascript execution - it doesnt work as those calls are pretty limited.  You should just return the Id and then use a `Driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));` call to get your hands on the actual WebElement it represents.

I ended up having to write quite a lot of code as a mini framework around selenium to get going with this but that should get you started.

I think thats the nice thing about selenium though - it gives you the bare elements to work with and then lets you build your own stuff around that.

You'll also want to architect things as that guy suggest by putting things into '[pages](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html)'

Comment: personally I've actually found client side javascript acceptance tests are nicer to work with as they are much faster to execute but thats a whole other story (and actually involves using selenium anyway) see my [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311215/html-javascript-sharing-script-lists-or-doing-ci-with-jasmine-and-selenium)

Comment: So I guess there's no open source framework for ExtJS testing and I need to write my own, e.g., using your approach. Right?

Comment: @dzieciou not that I know of.  I wouldn't recommend using selenium to test ExtJs - because its doing wacky asynchronous stuff all the time it causes a lot of problems.  It's easier to test from js, but you'll have to dig all your code out of the views/controllers.  That way you can avoid some of its quirky ui behaviour and can do your waiting by hooking into the ext direct method calls... either way its a bit of nightmare to be honest, but then that's how I'd probably describe the framework as a whole!